# UITableViewCell height based on available screen space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I wanted to create a layout for my `UITableView` such that it's divided into 2 sections:
 the first section has 3 rows of standard height (44px), 
and the second section has one row, which contains a `UITextView` which completely fills up this cell. The tricky part is that I want to size this `textView`'s cell row to the height of the visible `tableview` area, such that the text view takes up the remaining view on screen. How do I find out, within

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

what the remaining height looks like? I had previously made hard-coded assumptions based on the two iPhone screen sizes available (480 and 568) but with the new iPhone6 and iPhone 6+ screen, I don't want to use any assumed values for calculating this.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding `480` or `568` is checking `self.view.bounds.size.height` not good enough?

Comment: It might be. But how do I offset it from the start of the cell? Within `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, the UITableViewCell (from section:1 row:0) doesn't return a meaningful frame to figure out where in the tableview this cell is (vertically)

Comment: You can get current table sroll view offset using the `tableView.contentOffset.y`. Then it's just a matter of calculation. If you need to take header heights and stuff into account you can get them using the `[tableView heightForHeaderInSection:]` etc. If you can post some images and give a little more detail I might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the height of the table view at `tableView.bounds.size.height`, you just need the height of the first section subtracted from it. so

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        return 44;
    }

    return tableView.bounds.size.height - 44 * 3;
}
```

With the headers, depending on how they behave, you can use `rectForHeaderInSection:` or `rectForSection:` to get the heights

Comment: The section headers have heights too, so this would be inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you will never change the number of rows you can do this static from storyboard.
You can insert prototype cells as many as you need. And with autolayout or autosizing you can set the cells to be static or to increase with size of screen.

But if you really want to make it programmatically you get the screen height with `self.view.bounds.size.height` withdraw the 3 cells and 2 headers of section and the remaining is your  UITextView cell.

Comment: Not sure how you can use auto-layout here. We need to calculate the size of the UITableViewCell based on the available space. Not sure how auto-layout would do this (other than setting the constants in code after calculating the height, which is the problem anyways)

Comment: You can by keeping the first section without any autosizing and only the cell you need it dynamically should have UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin and UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight